# Did the .vbox file disappear in some version of VirtualBox before 4.1.2?

Tags: virtualbox

I keep seeing people in the forums refering to the *.vbox file of their VM, but I don't see the file anywhere within my own installations.

My hunch is that they've changed the name of the file to <Machine-Name>.xml but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the .vbox in the following path:
C:\Users\(Name of User)\VirtualBox VMs\(Name of Hardware)

Answer (score 0):

No, I still see it:
[image]

Maybe you're not looking in the right place?

Comment: I see a file called : WordpressThemeDevBox.xml and another called WordpressThemeDevBox.xml-prev, in the %USERPROFILE%\.VirtualBox\Machines\WordpressThemeDevBox directory, that seems pretty similar...

Comment: So are they the same thing?

Comment: For a while there I was thinking that it had something to do with if you were running Windows or Linux, but it appears that you're running Windows.... :-p

Comment: Yes, Windows 7 x64 host.  Is it not in the same folder as the .vdi file?

Comment: Right, this was by choice.  But I also don't have .vbox files I have .xml files instead (although they seem to serve the same purpose).

Comment: I agree.  Opening the .vbox file in notepad yields: <?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: Well that just means it's an XML file, that doesn't mean its exactly the same thing, but it probably is...